# Connect phone as serial mouse via virtual serial port

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port, mouse

I am new to android programming. currently I am working on a android apps to make the phone as a serial mouse that connect to pc via bluetooth virtual serial port. I use Teraterm to get my phone connected to the pc and set the baudrate as 1200, 7 bits and 1 stop bit. I tried to connect to pc and send out the data packet of serial mouse in 3-byte format as stated in http://www.epanorama.net/documents/pc/mouse.html. When I send out the data packet, I thought the pc should recognise it as a serial mouse automatically but still,no response is received.

My question is that

(1) for the 3-byte data packet, should I send out one byte by one byte or save it in an array with 3 bytes each? currently I am saving it as array form.

(2) Do I need to send out any command to the pc as mouse identification? but from  I have read through from the post [Device misdetected as serial mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226082/device-misdetected-as-serial-mouse), it is recognized as mouse which is not intended.

Thanks in advance.